# liquibase-maven-plugin getting failed to execute the goal

Tags: maven, liquibase

I have integrated the liquibase in my project and added the liquibase plugin in pom.xml. It is working fine on my local system, but after checked in into the github, the staging build getting failed with the following error:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[1;34mINFO[m] Parsing Liquibase Properties File
[[1;34mINFO[m]   File: src/main/resources/liquibase.properties
[[1;34mINFO[m] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[1;34mINFO[m] Starting Liquibase at Thu, 17 Jan 2019 15:24:09 IST (version 3.6.1 built at 2018-04-11 09:05:04)
[[1;34mINFO[m] Executing on Database: jdbc:mysql://10.264.230.308/imsstaging?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Total time: 3.210 s
[[1;34mINFO[m] Finished at: 2019-01-17T15:24:10+05:30
[[1;34mINFO[m] Final Memory: 16M/121M
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] Failed to execute goal [32morg.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.1:update[m [1m(default)[m on project [36mede-app[m: [1;31mExecution default of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.1:update failed: [m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mNo X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] -> [1m[Help 1][m
```

#### POM.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>update</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: try to execute maven with parameter -e to see where is the error.

Comment: Have you googled the error message "No X11 DISPLAY variable..." ?

Comment: Thanks @bilak after checking the error I came to know the issue and that was exactly which "Jens" mentioned and resolution to this is I have to put the      <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
entry in the plugin and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

Inside the plugin I used the tag  as false and it worked.

```
<configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
</configuration>
```

Here are the full details:

http://blog.nutpan.com/2012/03/liquibase-maven-plugin-issue-with-non.html